Next Image is failing to fetch image with Docker Compose in a client component
I've api & web services in the docker-compose.yaml file. Currently everything works perfectly except Next Image(next/image) failing on a client component.
As the component is a client component it should fetch the image. Following is the error in cli (so it runs in server).
TypeError: fetch failed
web  |     at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13178:13
web  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
web  |     at async fetchExternalImage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1_sass@1.77.8/node_modules/next/dist/server/image-optimizer.js:580:17)
web  |     at async DevServer.imageOptimizer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1_sass@1.77.8/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:650:48)
web  |     at async cacheEntry.imageResponseCache.get.incrementalCache (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1_sass@1.77.8/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:182:65)
web  |     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1_sass@1.77.8/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:90:36
web  |     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.5_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1_sass@1.77.8/node_modules/next/dist/lib/batcher.js:45:32 {
web  |   [cause]: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]:
web  |       at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1118:18)
web  |       at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1685:7)
web  |       at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
web  |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web  |     [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
web  |   }
web  | }
web  |  GET /_next/image?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fuploads%2Fsample%2F9.png&w=1200&q=75 500 in 41ms
web  |  GET /_next/image?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fuploads%2Fsample%2F9.png&w=1200&q=75 500 in 29ms

Note: The images (pictures) this failed to fetch are available with the API URL (http://localhost:3000/uploads/sample/9.png) from host.
Following is the component
'use client'
import Image from "next/image";

type PostImgProps = {
  imgUrl: string;
};

const PostImg = (p: PostImgProps) => {
  // if I comment out the "Image" below there's no error remains
  return (
    <Image
      className="object-cover"
      src={p.imgUrl}
      alt="post image"
      width={1200}
      height={1000}
    />
  );
};

export default PostImg;

I know that Next.js tries to render client components in the server too. So I've imported it like
const PostImg = dynamic(
  () => import('@/path/to/postImg'),
  {
    ssr: false, // completely disable server side rendering
    loading: () => (
      <div className="...">
        <!-- loader code -->
      </div>
    )
  }
);

to disable server rendering. But I am still facing the error. As far as I can tell. As the component is still being rendered on the server. It fails to pull the image because the URL (p.imgUrl in PostImg component) is unavailable on the server. btw, it's http://localhost:3xxx/path/to/img.ext. In the server instead of localhost we need docker service name there which is api in my case. but how do I configure that?
Thank you in advance for the help :)
Node: 20
Next: 14.2.5


Please [edit] the question to clarify both what's going wrong and how to reproduce it.  A link to another question isn't enough; each question should contain its own [mre].

I've updated the question as per your recommendation.
